# Is a custom UIActivity with the bookmark icon possible?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiactivityviewcontroller

Part of my iOS app is a file viewer with a UIActivityViewController. From it, I would like users to be able to do normal activity view stuff with the file, like mailing it, saving it to photos (if it's a photo), and everything else. However, my app has a bookmarks feature. I would like for users to be able to bookmark files from this menu. I have created a custom UIActivity to add the object to the bookmarks list, but I have not been able to figure out how to have it use the system bookmark icon. Is this even possible?

**EDIT:** For clarification, this is in the menu that you get when you click a "share" button.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy. It all depends on how you are initiating it, is it in a navigation controller, swipe gesture, toolbar item or just a regular button? Either way it doesn't matter but if you want a specific answer you'll have to ask a specific question.

Here is an example how to accomplish your goal buy using a bookmark button that is connected in Storyboard interface, however the IBActions for addToFav and download aren't an interface and don't need to be:

```
-(IBAction) moreActions:(id)sender {
UIActionSheet *moreActions = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Add To Favorites", @"Download For Offline View",@"Open Document In :", nil];
[moreActions showInView:self.view];
}
```

And the way you perform actions is by calling the method below:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0: [self addToFav:self]; //See IBAction below
        break;
    case 1: [self download:self]; //See IBAction below
        break;
    case 2: {
        //UIDocumentInteractionController:

        NSURL *docURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"filePathStringHere"];

        documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:docURL];
        [documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
        [documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
        break;
}
```

}

```
 - (IBAction)download:(id)sender {
//enter your download code here
}

- (IBAction)addToFav:(id)sender {
//Code to add to your favorites
}
```